# How I do I automate Xamarin.iOS unit test project

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How I do I automate Xamarin.iOS unit test project.

For Android, I found this link which worked fine.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/automate-android-nunit-test/

Is there any references like this for Xamarin.iOS too?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, I don't believe what you'd like to do is possible. If I take your meaning, you'd probably like to say "Run All" with some test runner (presumably in XS or VS) and then get the results immediately, but that's not how it works with Xamarin.iOS. I'm sure you've already glanced at Xamarin's iOS testing quick-start, but if not [here that is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/touch.unit).

You have to set up a Unit Test app that uses the [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/xamarin/Touch.Unit) framework, fire up the test app, and "touch" the tests you'd like to run. My experience doing this has not been so great. The runner itself seems buggy and you're limited with in what other tools you can use (e.g., mocking frameworks won't work, assertions made with [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) won't register). I guess it's better than nothing, though!